# Programming transition matrix for chess pieces

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement

### Situation

I am currently trying to program the transition matrix for the king in the game of chess. We know that, on a 8x8 board, the probability of the king reaching a space j from a space i, where i,j = 1, 2, 3,..., 64 is

p(i,j) = 1/d(i) where d(i) # of adjacent spaces to i **if i and j are adjacent**

---

### Attempt in R

My approach is exhaustive: to loop on all squares and increment a variable d equal to the number of adjacent squares whose belong to the set of all squares 1, 2,..., 64.

```
P = matrix(0, ncol = 64, nrow = 64)

for(i in 1:64){
  d <- 0

  if((i + 6) %in% 1:64){
    d <- d + 1
  } else if((i - 6) %in% 1:64){
    d <- d + 1
  } else if((i - 10) %in% 1:64){
    d <- d + 1
  } else if((i + 10) %in% 1:64){
    d <- d + 1
  } else if((i - 15) %in% 1:64){
    d <- d + 1
  } else if((i + 15) %in% 1:64){
    d <- d + 1
  } else if((i - 17) %in% 1:64){
    d <- d + 1
  } else if((i + 17) %in% 1:64){
    d <- d + 1
  }

  if((i + 6) %in% 1:64){
    P[i, i + 6] = 1/d
  } else if((i - 6) %in% 1:64){
    P[i, i - 6] = 1/d
  } else if((i - 10) %in% 1:64){
    P[i, i - 10] = 1/d
  } else if((i + 10) %in% 1:64){
    P[i, i + 10] = 1/d
  } else if((i - 15) %in% 1:64){
    P[i, i - 15] = 1/d
  } else if((i + 15) %in% 1:64){
    P[i, i + 15] = 1/d
  } else if((i - 17) %in% 1:64){
    P[i, i - 17] = 1/d
  } else if((i + 17) %in% 1:64){
    P[i, i + 17] = 1/d
  }

}
```

---

### Problem

The variable d does not seem to increment as expected. It should have values between 3 (if the king is in the corners) or 8 (if the king is not in first or last rank or files). I seem to be getting only values of 1 for d. **In other words, d does not seem to increment after the first if statement.**

This can be seen if add print(d) after d is incremented.

Answer (score 1):

The code below should be able to create the transition probability matrix you want. Basically I'm creating a function, using four criteria to determine whether two tiles `(i,j)` are adjacent. I assume the chessboard is numbered 1 to 8 on the top row, 9 to 16 on the second, so on until 55 to 64 on the bottom row.

1. Vertically adjacent: `i-j` should equal `-8` or `8`.
2. Horizontally adjacent: `i-j` should equal `-1` or `1`, and to ensure `i` and `j` are in the same row, `i-1` and `j-1` should have same remainder when divided by 8.
3. Diagonally adjacent, top right - bottom left: `i-j` should equal `-7` or `7` and to ensure they are in different rows, `i-1` and `j-1` should have different remainder when divided by 8.
4. Diagonally adjacent, top left - bottom right: `i-j` should equal `-9` or `9`, and to ensure they are in adjacent rows, `i-1` and `j-1` when divided by 8 should have remainders differ by 1. (Note that `i` and `j` can differ by 9 and be located not in adjacent rows e.g. `8` in row 1 and `17` in row 3.)

Finally, dividing by row sums because a transition probability matrix has row sums of 1 (total probability).

```
P = matrix(0, nrow=64, ncol=64)

is_adjacent = function(i,j){
  #Adjacent vertically
  if(abs(i-j) == 8){
    print(1)
    return(TRUE)
  }
  #Adjacent horizontally
  else if(abs(i-j) == 1 & (i-1)%/%8 == (j-1)%/%8){
    print(2)
    return(TRUE)
  }
  #Adjacent diagonal upper right - bottom left
  else if(abs(i-j) == 7 & (i-1)%/%8 != (j-1)%/%8){
    print(3)
    return(TRUE)
  }
  #Adjacent diagonal upper left - bottom right
  else if(abs(i-j) == 9 & abs((i-1)%/%8 - (j-1)%/%8) == 1){
    print(4)
    return(TRUE)
  }
  else
    return(FALSE)
}

for(i in 1:64){
  for(j in 1:64){
    if(is_adjacent(i,j)) P[i,j]=P[i,j]+1
  }
}


P = P/rowSums(P)
```

P.S.: The transition probability matrix reminds me of discrete-time Markov chain, is that what are you doing?